# Show Color Picker Value Code Within Input Text Field in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, admin

Hi i have options page for my theme i used color picker jquery plugin in my options page as show in image below.

[image]

i want when i change the color from color picker automatically show the color value code within the text field.how can do this?

this is the code within my options page related to appearing the color picker and text field

function to register the options setting

```
function YPE_register_settings_sections_fields() {

    register_setting (
        'YPE_header_option_group', 
        'YPE_header_option_name',
        'YPE_sanitize_validate_callback'
    );
    add_settings_section (
        'YPE_header_section', 
        'Header Section', 
        'YPE_header_section_callback', 
        'YPE_menu_page_options'
    );
    add_settings_field (
        'YPE_header_bg', 
        'Header Background', 
        'YPE_header_bg_callback', 
        'YPE_menu_page_options',
        'YPE_header_section'
    );
}
 add_action('admin_init', 'YPE_register_settings_sections_fields');
```

function to appear the text field and color picker

```
function YPE_header_bg_callback() {
    $YPE_options = get_option('YPE_header_option_name');
    $YPE_header_bg = isset($YPE_options['YPE_header_bg']) ? $YPE_options['YPE_header_bg'] : '';

    ?>
        <div class="input-group color-picker">
            <input class="form-control" style="width:80px;"  name="YPE_header_option_name[YPE_header_bg]" id="<?php echo 'YPE_header_bg'; ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $YPE_header_bg; ?>" /> 
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <div id="colorSelector">
                    <div nam style="background-color: #0000ff">  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </span>
        </div>

        <script>
            $("#colorSelector").ColorPicker({
                color: '#0000ff',
                onShow: function (colpkr) {
                    $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
                    return false;
                },
                onHide: function (colpkr) {
                    $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
                    return false;
                },
                onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                    $('#colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
            });
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

This is my console JavaScript error if you can read errors and help me for solving my problem
[image]

Comment: when i change the color value in color picker don't show the color value in text field

Comment: @Rahil Wazir i used your answer code but don't work with me

Comment: Right, my point was that you hadn't tried anything to make it work yourself. You just need to assign the hex code to the input element once the color is selected.

Comment: @doublesharp yes but only i want assign the hex code to input field when i select the color. but i can't do this please help me

Comment: both of the answers below are correct

Comment: but why don't work with me ?

Comment: you have a syntax error as well.

Comment: Fix the errors in your console. Why ColorPicker is bind to null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your code...

- [WordPress uses jQuery](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) in [`noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) mode, so you need to use `jQuery` and not `$`.
- There is a missing a closing curly brace `}` after the `onChange` function.
- There is no need for `return false;` in your `onShow` and `onHide` functions.
- Add code to your `onChange` function to assign the `hex` value to your `#YPE_header_bg` `input` element.

***Example code:***

```
<script>
jQuery("#colorSelector").ColorPicker({
    color: '#0000ff',
    onShow: function (colpkr) {
        jQuery(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
    },
    onHide: function (colpkr) {
        jQuery(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
    },
    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
        jQuery('#colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
        jQuery('#YPE_header_bg').val('#' + hex);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: after using your code also don't work with me and don't show color hex within my input field. if you want whole my options code please see my codes and take me the full solution because for 5 days i try to solve this problem but i can't

Comment: yes i have console errors you can see my console errors in image below

Comment: Sorry, it looks like you have issues well beyond the scope of this question - jQuery is not loading, your color picker may not be either. Get it working normally first and the code in this answer will work for the issue you asked the question about.

Comment: please help me i if you can i want send you whole my folder of my options page and test on it see my color picker problem i'm very tied with this problem for 5 days i try and searched in all webdesign sites without any benefit please help me and test my files on your server and solve my problem

Comment: I did see one other issue, WordPress uses jQuery in `noConflict()` mode which means `$` is aliased to `jQuery` - try replacing the jQuery references as I have in my answer. Beyond that it sounds like this might be too large of a scope for SO.

Comment: after 5 days only i added simple code and solved my problem we forget using jQuery(function() { in start and }); in end after adding this code now all things is true my problem it is solved and you very helped me thank you my brother

Comment: Great, glad you got it working. Would you mind marking this as the answer, thanks!

Comment: hi but i have simple problem. if i want use this color picker more than one time how can i do this? when i past above code only the first one work another color pickers don't work because all have the same id (colorSelector) and when i change the id also not work because in the color picker folder have layout.css file only defined (colorSelector) id

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply add this line of code on your `onChange` method and I assume your color input box id is `YPE_header_bg`:

```
onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
    $('#colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
    $('#YPE_header_bg').val('#' + hex);
```

Comment: hi i tried to use your edit code but also don't work with me please if you can edit all my code then past here

Comment: @ShwanNamiq Make sure the input color box id is `YPE_header_bg'?